# Получить Атрибуты Директории C#

Tags: c#, .net, атрибуты

В C# имеется вот такая конструкция:

```
File.GetAttributes(path);
```

Такая кострукция помогает узнать какие атрибуты у файла по указанному в path пути(ReadOnly, System, Hide и т.д).
Мне нужно получить атрибуты директории. Но вот такой кострукции как с файлами не вижу. 
Как эта задача решается на C# т.е как получить атрибуты директории?

Comment: DirictoryInfo попробуй.

Answer (score 0):

Например, так:
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
var attr = dir.Attributes;

Comment: Так ведь мне нужно узнать какие атрибуты у директории чтобы понять, можно ли его удалить
Условие такое:
`если атрибут != System то удалить директорию`.

Comment: Так ведь есть свойство Attribute.

Comment: Оно применЯется только к файлам, а нужно к директориям.

Comment: Кажется понял, как использовать Info. Завтра попробую.

Comment: Просто проверить необходимый атрибут через метод HasFlag(..), например, так:

DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo("c:\\windows");
if (info.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.System)) {
   ... делаем что-то ...
}

Comment: вот про HasFlag не догадался бы сам, бился бы лбом об экран. Спасибо

Comment: @Leonax стоит добавить уточнение про флаги в сам ответ